# ASP.Net MVC - how to convert datetime in format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, datepicker

I have get error when i try to update table that have field with Datetime, this is the error :

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

in my database format datetime like this  :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"     Ex : 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000
```

but from My View the result format datetime is :

```
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"    Ex:  8/18/2017 00:00:00 AM
```

so that i get error and can not update,
anyone please help me for my problem. thank you

Comment: What code generates the error? (dates in a database do not have a format -you just seeing how your database displays it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ooh, i just knew that Dates in database don't have a format. If like that, i think the error maybe come from my Controller, can i copy my code in this comment ? if you don't mind.
when i update it from my view, i get the date from datepicker format,

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question. But does the culture on your server expect dates in that format? (if not then you need to change the culture, or create a custom ModelBinder)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you're right , the error is from ModelBinderExtension\DateTimeModelBinder.cs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you're right , the error is from ModelBinderExtension\DateTimeModelBinder.cs. but i don't know how to fix this.

the error from this code :

    return DateTime.ParseExact(date.Trim().Split(' ')[0], _customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 2):

```html
Convert.ToDateTime(Your date variable, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

You can convert the date by using the above code

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems you are saving your date as a string type. Before format your date you need to create a DateTime object:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(model.dateValue);
var printInfo = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", date);
```

Use the value in printInfo to show in your html.

You can also use:

```
// Sample 01:
Convert.ToDateTime(model.dateValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Sample 02:
DateTime.Parse(model.dateValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// Sample 03:
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Parse(model.dateValue));
```